# What is $\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\dots)))$?

Tags: gamma-function, nested-radicals

Consider the infinitely nested expression

$$x=\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\dots)))$$

where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Imitating the [standard method for solving infinitely nested radicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Infinitely_nested_radicals), we can write

$$\Gamma(1+x)=x$$

and solve for $x$. This yields two positive solutions: $1$ and $2$.

If we instead imagine that the "$\dots$" part of the *"innermost term"* (hand waving here) disappears then that term becomes $\Gamma(1)=1$, the surrounding term becomes $\Gamma(2)=1$ and the hierarchy collapses until $\Gamma(2)=1$ remains.

What, then, about the "solution" $x=2$ we derived using the first method? Is either of these solutions valid? Or is it impossible to assign a unique meaningful value to the infinite expression in the first place?

Comment: You want the limit, if it exists, of the sequence $x_n = \Gamma(1 + x_{n-1})$ with, say, initial condition $x_0 = 1$. This is perfectly well-defined. It's clear that if the limit $L$ exists then $L = \Gamma(1 + L)$, and if there are multiple $L$ with this property then in general the initial condition will determine which $L$ actually ends up being the limit, again if it exists.

Comment: To complete the previous comment, there are exactly two solutions (in the nonnegative real line) of $L=\Gamma(1+L)$, namely $L=1$ and $L=2$, and $x_n\to1$ for every $x_0$ in $[0,2)$, $x_n\to2$ if $x_0=2$, and $x_n\to\infty$ for every $x_0$ in $(2,\infty)$. (One says that $L=1$ is an attractive fixed point while $L=2$ is a repulsive fixed point.)

Comment: To elaborate on the above comment, we can confirm that $L=1$ is an attractive fixed point by computing $|\Gamma'(1+1)|=|1-\gamma|<1$, and that $L=2$ is a repulsive fixed point by computing $|\Gamma'(1+2)|=|3-2\gamma|>1$. (A general formula for $\Gamma'$ at positive integers is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General).)

Comment: Ah, the Pacman constant.

Answer (score 3):

The infinitely nested gamma functions equation can be solved (as you suggest) by the standard method for infinite nesting:
$$
\begin{align}
x    &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\cdots)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+x)\\
     &= x\Gamma(x)\\
\Gamma(x)
     &= 1\\
x    &= 1,2
\end{align}
$$

Plugging in $x=1$ solves the equation:
$$
\begin{align}
x    &= \Gamma(1+1)\\\
     &= \Gamma(2)\\
     &= 1
\end{align}
$$

And plugging in $x=2$ also solves the equation:
$$
\begin{align}
x    &= \Gamma(1+2)\\
     &= \Gamma(3)\\
     &= 2\Gamma(2)\\
     &= 2
\end{align}
$$

So both $x=1$ and $x=2$, are the solutions for the original equation.

---

Your *hand-waving* argument is invalid, because you are effectively taking the assumption that $(\cdots=)\ x=0,$ and then proving that $x=1$:
$$
\color{grey}{
\begin{align}
x    &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\cdots)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+0)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+1))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(2))\\
     &= \Gamma(2)\\
     &= 1
\end{align}
}
$$

---

A similar *hand-waving* argument for the $x=1$ case is:
$$
\begin{align}
x    &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\cdots)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+1)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(2)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+1))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(2))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+1)\\
     &= \Gamma(2)\\
     &= 1
\end{align}
$$

And a *hand-waving* argument for the $x=2$ case is:
$$
\begin{align}
x    &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\cdots)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+2)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+\Gamma(3)))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(1+2))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+\Gamma(3))\\
     &= \Gamma(1+2)\\
     &= \Gamma(3)\\
     &= 2
\end{align}
$$

Unfortunately, both of these *hand-waving* arguments are indeed circular.

Comment: As far as I see it $|\Gamma'(2)|=|1-\gamma|<1$ and $|\Gamma'(3)|=|3-2\gamma|>1$, so $x=1$ should contain an entire neighbourhood whose values all map onto $1$, while $x=2$ is repelling.